# Transformation from long to wide with multiple observations in R

Tags: r, dcast, wide-format-data

I want to transform a data set from long to wide.
The data contains multiple observations for each time point.

To illustrate, consider the following two examples.

In EXAMPLE 1 below, the data *does not contain multiple observations* and can be transformed from long to wide.

In EXAMPLE 2 below, the data *does contain multiple observations* (n=3 per time point) and cannot be transformed from long to wide, testing with `dcast` and `pivot_wider`.

Can anyone suggest a method to transform the test data from EXAMPLE 2 into a valid format?

Code to reproduce the problem:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggcorrplot)
library(reshape2)
library(tidyr)
library(data.table)

# EXAMPLE 1 (does work)
# Test data
set.seed(5)
time    <- rep(c(0,10), 1, each = 2)
feature <- rep(c("feat1", "feat2"), 2)
values  <- runif(4, min=0, max=1)

# Concatenate test data
# test has non-unique values in time column
test    <- data.table(time, feature, values)

# Transform data into wide format
test_wide <- dcast(test, time ~ feature, value.var = 'values')

# EXAMPLE 2 (does not work)
# Test data
set.seed(5)
time    <- rep(c(0,10), 2, each = 6)
feature <- c(rep("feat1", 12), rep("feat2", 12))
values  <- runif(24, min=0, max=1)

# Concatenate test data
# test has non-unique values in time column
test    <- data.table(time, feature, values)

# Transform data into wide format
test_wide <- dcast(test, time ~ feature, value.var = 'values')
```

**Warning:**

```
Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
```

**Problem:**

Non-unique values in first column (`time`) are not preserved/allowed.

```
# Testing with pivot_wider
test_wider <- pivot_wider(test, names_from = feature, values_from = values)
```

**Warning:**

```
Warning message:
Values are not uniquely identified; output will contain list-cols.
```

**Problem:**

Non-unique values in first column (`time`) are not preserved/allowed.

In lack of a better idea, a *possible* **output** could look like this:

| time | feat1 | feat2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.1046501 | 0.5279600 |
| 0 | 0.7010575 | 0.8079352 |
| 0 | 0.2002145 | 0.9565001 |

etc.

Comment: What's wrong with `cor(mtcars)`?

Comment: Nothing, this is the example that works and what I want to do with the test data in the end. However, I cannot transform the test data into a format which can be used for cor().

Comment: (The original ```mtcars``` data set has only one observation per car.)

Comment: I would suggest using `tidy::pivot_wider`, but I don't really know what you expect your final output to be.  Your question would be clearer if you focused on the starting and ending data structure and omit the stuff about correlation matrices and `mtcars`.

Comment: Thank you! I edited the question and adapted the example to make it more clear. I also tested your suggestion ```pivot_wider```, and it does not work due to multiple observations in the data set.

Comment: Both your `dcast` and the `pivot_wider` commands actually give outputs.  What is wrong with the output? What do you want `test_wide` to look like?  Please be explicit.

Comment: As mentioned in the title of the question, the data contains multiple observations. These are not retained in the output of the above attempts in EXAMPLE 2. I am trying to find a way which allows non-unique elements in the first column of the output data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since there are multiple values, it is not obvious how these should be treated when converting to a wide format.  That's why you get the warning messages.  This is one way of handling them.  If you want something else, then please give a *specific* example of *what the output should look like*.

```
pivot_wider(test, names_from = feature, values_from = values) %>% 
    unnest(c(feat1, feat2))
```

Comment: Please give the exact numbers that you want to appear in each row and column.

Comment: Also, I think you are confused about what `test` contains.  There is no mixing between time and feature.  Please check.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out and sorry for the confusion. I corrected the part in the code.

Comment: I added a possible output to the original post. Again, sorry for the confusion before.

Comment: With your new example `test`, my solution gives something with the same form.  _However_, the way to pair up the values is ill-defined.  Computing correlations might not make sense, unless your real data already has the ordering in place.

Comment: Thanks, you are right, your solution gives the output as stated above. And you are right, this approach is not ideal. If you have a better suggestion, I would really appreciate your input. 
In the real data set, the are simply 3 measurements for each time point. The order of these three measurements within time point is irrelevant, as long as all measurements belonging to the same time point are correctly paired.


Btw, we are not there yet: When using the output from above with ```cor()```, correlations are calculated for ```time``` as well (which is not anticipated).

Comment: For the last point, about `time` appearing in the correlation matrix, either simply ignore those rows and columns, or drop `time` from your data.frame before applying `cor()`.  As to your real question about how to analyze the relationship between ordered pairs of triplets, perhaps you should ask at [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).

Comment: That's the point. I cannot ignore ```time```, because in that case, the three observations for each time point cannot be mapped correctly. Thanks for the suggestion, I will try Cross Validated. I will accept your answer since it generates the output stated in the question. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You may want something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = c(feature, time), 
              values_from = values)
```

where the c(feature, times) accounts for the multiple variable case. But as was already pointed out in the comments please indicate if you want something else.

Comment: Thanks. Testing your method retrieves a 1x2 data structure, which is not the expected output. However, I updated/corrected the original post. This might have caused your answer to show a different output.

Comment: Thanks for the update. That ```feat1``` and ```feat2``` are exact duplicates of each other may cause the problem.

Comment: Thanks for spotting that. I corrected it in the original post. A correct solution to the question was accepted.